# Auto-updated key value in consul?

Tags: consul, consul-kv

In the consul ui demo (https://demo.consul.io/ui/) each datacenter has a key called "global/time" which appears to show the current time, and is automatically updated.

Is this a standard feature of consul (couldn't find it in the docs)? If not, how is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like a standard feature of Consul. It can be implemented with a cron script that updates the K/V store in a local Consul agent every few seconds.